# MYSQL trigger for auditing by column changes

Tags: mysql, function, triggers, audit, declare

I have multiple tables and at the moment the audit to a table which is almost a clone and 1 to 1. I'm looking to make a single table for auditing purposes for all my tables, but instead of capturing all changes i would like to insert to the audit only the column name changes, old and new data.

Here is my concept trigger;

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_users_audit`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `tbl_users` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE @var1 nvarchar(max), @var1 nvarchar(max), @var1 nvarchar(max) 

    [... get values for var's ...]

    INSERT INTO `tbl_audit` (id_user, event_date, table_name, record_id, column_name, old_value, new_value)
    VALUES (NEW.update_userid, NEW.dtupdated, 'tbl_users', NEW.id, [@va1], [@var2], [@var3],)
END
```

I've searched the web for a few hours and not found many audit example triggers and the ones i found dont do anything like this. I think i need quite a bit of sql to get the 3 var's ready for the insert but im not sure what the appropriate functions are if there are any.

Any advice about the functions to use would be great.